# Azure Mobile Services for Android, how to use abstract classes as a table

Tags: java, android, azure, abstract-class, azure-mobile-services

So I'm currently having an issue with using an abstract class as a table, lets say I have this class

`public abstract class Profile {
    String id;
    String email;
    String password;
    String FirstName;
    String LastName;
    String PhoneNumber;
    //getters/setters below
}`

And I have this other class as a concrete class for Profile

`public class Student extends Profile {
    public Student(String id, String email, String password, String FirstName, String LastName, String PhoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
    }
}`

This isssue is that I have a `Profile` table in my database, but I cannot create an instance of a `MobileServiceTable<>` in my code because it is an abstract class and will throw this exception `"The class type used for creating a MobileServiceTable must be a concrete class"`

So what is the best way of going around this? Obviously my Profile abstract class has all the information I need to create a database table, but I can't instantiate the table as

`MobileServiceTable<Profile> profileTable = mClient.getTable(Profile.class)`

because it is abstract and will throw the exception. I've tried casting it to a student such as

`MobileServiceTable<Student> studentTable = mClient.getTable(Student.class)`

but that doesn't work since there isn't a `Student` table in my database, plus it says I need `Student.class` to use a unique `id` field as well, but that should be taken care of by the `Profile` class. Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Profile should be a concrete class if it matches an actual table. Why did you want it to be abstract?

Comment: I wanted it to be abstract so the developer would be forced to pick either a Student or Tutor implementation, which would have their own unique fields as well.

Comment: Is there no profile table then? From your question, you said there's no student table either.

Comment: There is a profile table with all the fields from the profile abstract class. Ideally I would like an instance of Student or Tutor to be saved to the profile table since it is their super class. Right now I'm currently using two identical tables named Student and Tutor to save each instance of Student and Tutor to, respectively.

Comment: If you have a concrete Profile, then it needs to be a concrete class. Your solution seems similar to how one might structure an OO system, but it doesn't make sense when dealing with a database.